# Design an AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently working to convert an existing app into angularjs app as much as possible. We've decided to handle all the modal windows using AngularJS which, currently, we handle with jQuery UI Dialog. I'm quite confused how I can design the app/controllers to maintain a hierarchy.

I've tried to lay the structure in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm9SR/1/) and described as necessary.

```
<body id="container" ng-app="MyApp" >
<div id="nav" ng-controller="NavController">
</div>

<div id="contents" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>Different types of static/dynamic contents go here</div>

    <div id="module-101" class="modules-block" ng-controller="EditModuleController" data-module-type="A">
        <a href="/modules/101/edit">Edit Module</a>
        MODULE CONTENTS

    </div>


    <div id="module-102" class="modules-block" ng-controller="EditModuleController"  data-module-type="B">
        <a href="/modules/102/edit">Edit Module</a>
        MODULE CONTENTS
    </div>


    <div id="module-103" class="modules-block" ng-controller="EditModuleController"  data-module-type="B">
        <a href="/modules/103/edit">Edit Module</a>
        MODULE CONTENTS
    </div>


    <div id="edit-module-modal">
        This will be loaded when page is loaded but will remain hidden. When 'Edit Module' is clicked, this area will be displayed in a modal. When modal is dispalyed; the controller (EditModuleController) will load required data from REST API and display that. This area can be displayed when any of the above 3 'Edit Module' is clicked'.          

        <div class="module-edit-container">
            <div class="module-edit-contents" ng-controller="Dynamically assign module type specific controller i.e. ModuleAController, ModuleBController">
                All module editing contents go here
            </div>

            <div class="modal-actions">
                <a href="What should be route here and which controller should handle this?">Save Module</a>
                <a href="similar as 'Save Module'">Cance</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="list-module-modal">
        This will be loaded when page is loaded but will remain hidden. When 'List Module' is clicked, this area will be displayed in a modal. When modal is dispalyed; the controller (ListModulesController) will load required data from REST API and display that.             
    </div>


</div>
```

Javascript

```
    angular.module('App', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/modules/:id/edit', {
        controller: 'EditModuleController',
        template: 'should show edit-module-modal in modal'
    })
    .when('/modules/list', {
        controller: 'ListModulesController,
        template: 'should show #list-module-modal in modal'
    })
    ;
}])
.controller('NavController', ['$scope', function($scope){ }])
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){ }])
.controller('EditModuleController', ['$scope', function($scope){ }])
.controller('ModuleAController', ['$scope', function($scope){ }])
.controller('ModuleBController', ['$scope', function($scope){ }])
```

Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm9SR/1/) link for better presentation.

Other than what is described in the html, I want module specific controllers (there will be a different controller for each module type; for example, module A, module B, Module N to handle that module specific editing operation as it varies greatly from module to module) to share some common functionalities like Loading data from REST API, Saving Data from Rest API etc. I can handle the data loading from server when module is initialized using Restangular and that part is working fine

I'm expecting advices how to structure the application. Other than those advices, here are some of my questions/problems that I faced:

- I see my controller isn't triggered when I don't mention `templateUrl` attribute in the $routeProvider
- As my module editing templates (displayed in the modal) are same for all modules, I don't want the template to load from server each time 'Edit Module' is clicked as this will just un-necessarily increase load. I want to load it during page load and wanna keep hidden.
- I'm ok, if I can't use route base structure here. I'm open for other suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a look @ ng-boilerplate https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp, it uses https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router, best-practice directory structure & grunt build management system.

Its a good working example of structuring an app with module specific controllers & routing.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But managing files isn't my current concern rather architecting the app. However, I'm currently working with an idea that I got. I will update this thread if they work out for me